# Cómo re-dirigir a una página con SweetAlert

Tags: php, html, sweetalert, sweetalert2

tengo este cuadro de diálogo que aparece cuando sale un ERROR pero no he logrado que cuando le den click en OK los envié al index o la página donde estaban.

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script>
          jQuery(function(){
          swal("¡Error!", "Por favor, verifica los datos e intenta de nuevo", "warning");});</script>"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puede hacer algo asi:

```js
swal({
  title: "Deseas ser redirigido",
  text: "",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
   //redirect
   window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
  } else {
    swal("Operacion cancelada !!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

espero te sirva y te sugiero revisar la documentacion oficial:
[SweetAlertJs Documentacion](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started)